Can you use arrayformula and hyperlink together?
I have a column that has a full URL that I can covert to a short link in another cell using the following formula.
=HYPERLINK(C4,"Edit Submission")

When I try to do this same formula using an arrayformula so this column will update whenever a new entry is made to the sheet it does not work.

={“Edit Submission”;
ARRAYFORMULA(HYPERLINK(C4,"Edit Submission"))}

Can these two fuctions beused in this way? If not, what are my options?

To generate hyperlinks for a whole column (starting from cell C4 as per your question), you would use:
=arrayformula(hyperlink(C4:C,"Edit submission"))

If you wish to skip empty cells in column C and/or have different link text for each hyperlink, additional code will be required (although this is not obvious from your question).
